# Can not open a project which include bin lib obj

Tags: visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

I am very new to C# and Visual Studio. I have a project example and I am trying to create it again by myself. But I couldn't because there is a file hierarchy which I don't know. It's solution explorer like :

```
-Solution 'XXX'
 -ProjectName1
   -Properties
   -References
   -App.config
   -Program.cs
 -ProjectName2
   -Properties
   -References
   -bin
   -lib
   -obj
   -Class
```

First, I create Console Application and the first "ProjectName1" is coming with this. But I couldn't create something like this hierarchy in the second one "ProjectName2".

I tried to create a new Console App into the XXX, but there is a hierarchy like ProjectName1, I have to create something which is include bin, lib and obj.

Comment: Are you trying to do this with the project templates?

Comment: bin, lib, obj are just temp folders created by VS to hold temp files while building the exe.. you shouldn't be messing with them...

Comment: @gbianchi, not sure I'd refer to the actual program assemblies (the contents of "bin") as "temp" files...

Comment: So, if I create a new Console App into the Solution folder, is that enough?

Comment: The "bin" include "debug" and dlls

Comment: @KirkWoll well.. yeah.. unless you will deploy the debug folder.. but yeah.. bin/release is not temp as temp.. but you can always have a post operation that copy the output somewhere else..

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly:

1. open up your solution
2. right click your solution in solution explorer tab
3. add/New Project
4. Select Console Application
5. Name it ProjectName2
6. Click OK

Hope this will be helpful

and when you build it, it'll have bin etc. directories.

Comment: Frankly, there is another question too. I create the "ProjectName2" but there is a "class" thing which is not program.cs

What am I going to do with the program.cs of ProjectName2. There is only ABC class and it is not a program.cs. Should I delete to the program.cs of ProjectName2?

Comment: Program.cs is generated by Visual Studio. It contains the main function of your console application. You can call ABC class functions from your main function or create ABC class objects.

Comment: I knew it, but in the "ProjectName2" , there is only a class , not a program.cs. Should I delete the program.cs for staying only the class?

Answer (score 0):

A solution is a VS concept it doesn't mean much outside of VS.
A solution can contain multiple projects and/or files. projects are how you can build exe/web/dll assemblies. each project will become it's own assembly.

projects can contain references to each other (avoid bidirectional references) project A depends on Project B & C. Project B depends on D, etc.

bin & obj are where the assemblies are compiled to. bin is the current assembly and all dependencies. obj is just this project's assembly.

lib is most likely where 3rd party libraries would go, but I haven' seen that generated automatically before.

Comment: I undertstand with this explanation. I assumed that these bin, lib and obj are created with creating the new console app. Thank you